# Recursively Create Directory based on Elements (Web-Scraping using Selenium / BS4)

Tags: python, selenium, recursion, web-scraping

#### Context

I am trying to automatically download data from Blackboard, a site that often posts homework.

On the site, there are either **Folders** or **Items**. I am having difficulties replicating the structure of **Folders** locally, mainly because I can't do it recursively. For example, given that the following are the imaginary folder names with its structure:

```
- Lecture 1
-- Reading
--- Interesting stuffs
---- Very, very interesting stuffs
--- Less interesting stuffs

- Lecture 2
-- Reading

- Lecture 3
-- Homework
```

#### Question

Can anyone guide me in creating a recursive function for replicating the folder structure, given that we do not know the depth of the folders?

#### Additional info

I am using Selenium to traverse the web pages and BeautifulSoup to parse the information. I am able to replicate the first site and create its relevant folders with folder names captured. I just need a way to recursively (1) enter a folder if it is a folder, (2) create the folders, (3) enter into new folders if it is a folder

**Reference:**

```
driver.get(site)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
html = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
folders = soup.find('div',{'class':'container clearfix'}).find("ul", {"id":"content_listContainer"}).findAll("li", {"class":"clearfix liItem read"})
contentFolderText, contentFolderLink, itemText, itemLink, misc = [[] for i in range(5)]
for folder in folders:
    if folder.find("img").get("alt") == "Content Folder":
        contentFolderText.append(folder.find("a").text.replace(u'\xa0', u''))
        contentFolderLink.append(folder.find("a").get('href'))
    elif folder.find("img").get("alt") == "Item":
        itemText.append(folder.find("a").text.replace(u'\xa0', u''))
        itemLink.append(folder.find("a").get('href'))

directory = 'Module Files'
sourceName = [os.path.join(directory, i) for i in contentFolderText]
sourceName = [re.sub(r'[^\w\s\\-]', '', i) for i in sourceName]
for folder in sourceName:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
         os.makedirs(folder)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!